# Run Macro inside Table

Tags: vba, excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUVBH.jpg)I would like to run a macro that sets my background color to green for one row in table, but if there are two tables next to each other, second tables gets as well the row in green:

[image]

Is there a way to get the background color only in the 1st Table, but without naming the Table. (For e.g. not naming "Set Table1 row color green"). Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub TEST()



Set LeftCell = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)
Set RightCell = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Columns.Count)
If IsEmpty(LeftCell) Then Set LeftCell = LeftCell.End(xlToRight)
If IsEmpty(RightCell) Then Set RightCell = RightCell.End(xlToLeft)
If LeftCell.Column = Columns.Count And RightCell.Column = 1 Then
    ActiveCell.Select
Else
    Range(LeftCell, RightCell).Select
End If

Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)

End Sub
```

Thanks
Roxana

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVEyr.jpg)

Comment: So you want it to remain green until they enter something? If so, this would be better accomplished by using Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. But how can I use Conditional Formatting in this case?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to happen? I'm still not clear on the behavior you expect. Can you post some additional screenshots in your question showing what it should look like with no text, and what it should look like after text is entered in to some cells.

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try...

```
Sub FillRowColor()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim tblName
    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = ActiveCell
    On Error Resume Next
    tblName = cell.ListObject.Name
    On Error GoTo 0
    If tblName <> "" Then
        Set tbl = ActiveCell.ListObject
        Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
        tbl.Range.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        tbl.Range.Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
    Else
        MsgBox "ActiveCell is not in the table.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: sktneer,  If I run this code I get all the cell in the Table with background black so I removed the second interior color after the "= RGB(146, 208, 80)". No it colors all the cells and rows in green.

Comment: @RoxanaVlad My bad, I don't know how they were duplicated, maybe during the copy and paste the code here. I have edited the code and it should work fine for you.

Comment: That's what I did as well, but now I get all the cells in the table filled with the color.

Comment: As per the code logic, any row where column 1 in the table is empty, that row would be highlighted as green. If you table is empty, all the rows would be colored green. How would you like to color a table row i.e. what should be the condition for coloring a table row green?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I added a new photo on how my result should look like. I have multiple macros for each row in an dynamic Table. In this e.g. I would like to color one specific row in the Table if my active cell is the first cell left in that table. My macro now runs until it finds the last cell in the second table and not in the first Table.

Comment: I still don't understand  what you are trying to achieve. Did you read the code logic I posted in my last comment? You added two images in the question and they both look similar except the colors. What I am missing here?

Comment: What I am trying to do is to format Tables using macros. I have created a Ribbon with buttons so each time I find myself in the first cell of one row, I want to run a macro only for that row, in that one Table. I added a new pic with the ribbon as well, Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Okay. I have edited the answer. See if that is what you were trying to achieve.